# Java clipboard access 10 second hang

Tags: java, linux, clipboard, x11

When I get the contents of the system clipboard, there is a small chance that the call will hang for exactly 10 seconds.

I ran into this because my popup menu creation would occasionally hang because I was checking the state of the clipboard to enable / disable a paste option.

After narrowing it down to getSystemClipboard().getContents(), I wrote a console app that just loops and queries it.  Under windows it runs fine, but under Linux and X, I get quite a few hangs.

In my GUI app, the 10 second hang will be cut short if there are any UI events (ie. mouse movement).

I've also ran my console app pointing to a Xvfb (headless X virtual frame buffer) and if there is only one console app connected to it hitting the clipboard it usually succeeds, but having a few copies of the app hitting the same X display the errors start happening.

Below is an example app.  I was wondering if this showed the same problem for you.

```
public class main {
    public static  void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Clipboard class: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getClass() );
        long progstart_ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int slowcount = 0;
        int MAXLOOP = 1000;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXLOOP; i++)
        {
            long start_ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
            long end_ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsed = end_ts - start_ts;

            if ( elapsed > 1000 )
            {
                System.out.println("Loop " + i + ", " + elapsed);
                slowcount++;
            }
        }
        long progend_ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long progelapsed = progend_ts - progstart_ts;
        System.out.println("Total time: " + progelapsed);
        System.out.println("Good/bad: " + (MAXLOOP - slowcount) + "/" + slowcount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect [this Java bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8078606) is related.  They claim it's fixed, but a thread dump during the hang shows that the AWT event thread is in fact waiting on a Lock, from within method XSelection.waitForSelectionNotify.

Comment: My analysis lead to the same method, `XSelection.waitForSelectionNotify`. The site says it's fixed in 8u60 and 9b70. I'm on 8u112

Comment: Found the actual bug, and it's closed without fix because of an incompetent tester. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7201163 == https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7201163